# Sending Firebase ID Token (not auth token) in request header with retrofit

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, retrofit2

I am using [Firebase ID Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) to authorise HTTP requests coming from users. Currently I have a request interceptor set up which will request for the Firebase ID Token and add it in the request header.

```
private OkHttpClient.Builder getOKHttpBuilder() {
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            Request.Builder newRequest = request.newBuilder().header("x-access-token", getNewTokenPassively());
            return chain.proceed(newRequest.build());
        }
    });

    return builder;
}

private String getNewTokenPassively() {
    FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    final String[] currentToken = {null};

    if(currentUser != null) {
        currentUser.getIdToken(false).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                try {
                    currentToken[0] = task.getResult().getToken();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    //TODO: Investigate
                }
            }
        });
    }

    while(currentToken[0] == null) {
        //do nothing
    }

    return currentToken[0];
}
```

This code works perfectly in SDK 24 and below but when run on SDK 25 and above the HTTP request does not flow through and nothing even gets logged on `logging-interceptor`.

I am using this interceptor with the below code.

```
public Retrofit getRetrofit() {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(getOKHttpBuilder().build())
            .addConverterFactory(converter)
            .build();
}
```

If I remove `.client(getOKHttpBuilder().build())` and replace it with `.client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().build())` everything works fine.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by "does not work in SDK 25 and above"?  Does it produce an error?  Is there a stack trace?  Does the getNewTokenPassively() function not return the right value, or not return at all?  Does something else happen or not happen?

Comment: I have edited the question to add more information.

Comment: @GiridharKarnik I am using this like this,

        OkHttpClient build = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor(new FirebaseUserIdTokenInterceptor())
                .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
                .build();

  In SDK 27 nothing gets logged on logging-interceptor.

Comment: You can use Tasks.await(task) instead of the whole while loop. This is a blocking call and will wait until result is returned.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is your getNewTokenPassively() function has an asynchronous onComplete call inside it.
you need to get token before adding it to request header.